# chrome.scripting.executeScript - Cannot read property 'executeScript' of undefined

Tags: google-chrome-extension, undefined

I am trying to change chrome extension from manifest_version 2 to manifest_version 3.
Something about the executeScript doesn't work for me...

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'executeScript' of undefined
```

That's part of my code:

```
chrome.webRequest.onResponseStarted.addListener(
    details => {
        chrome.scripting.executeScript(
            {
                target: { tabId: details.tabId },
                files: ['foreground.js']
            },
            () => { });
    },
    { urls: filteredURLs });
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Just added "scripting" to my "permissions".

```
{
    ...
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "webRequest",
        "scripting"
    ],
    ...
}
```